# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064; PDO and Cakephp-3

Tags: pdo, cakephp-3.0

this is my query, i dont know what's wrong with this

SELECT members.* AS `members__*`, accounts.* AS `accounts__*` FROM members INNER JOIN accounts  ON members.account_id=accounts.id

and showing this `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064`

is there anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: The problems in the query are obvious, the question is what does the code look like that produces this query?

Comment: It is produced by CakePHP-3 join function

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the not using " ` " symbol as it doesn't recognise correct names. And you need to name the new aliases in "ON" statement. 
Try the following query, it should work:

```
SELECT `members__*`.*, `accounts__*`.* FROM `members` as `members__*` INNER JOIN `accounts` AS `accounts__*` ON `members__*`.`account_id`=`accounts__*`.`id`
```

I suggest not using such names but if you really need to - go ahead :)